# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implemen tation found for method login on channel app.meedu/flutter_facebook_auth)

Tags: android, flutter

I'm getting the following error when I'm tring to sign in with facebook on android device by my flutter app  :

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method login on channel app.meedu/flutter_facebook_auth)
E/flutter (29705): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:175:7)
E/flutter (29705): 
E/flutter (29705): #1      FacebookAuthPlatformImplementation.login (package:flutter_facebook_auth_platform_interface/src/facebook_auth_implementation.dart:34:22)
E/flutter (29705):

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart your app.

Flutter has to inject plugin dependencies into the platform-specific parts of your app, hot restart/hot reload is not enough to trigger the injection. Check this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10912) for more.

Close the app and execute flutter run command.

Comment: I did all of this and it didn't work

Comment: I also did this and it still doesn't work. Is there any other reason for this error message or any other fixes to try please?

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop the iPhone / Android app.
2. Re-run application & make sure you did flutter pub get

It's work for me but Let me know if it's not work for you.